# Converting VBA function to Google Apps Script function

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I inherited a forecasting model file in Excel that uses a user-defined VBA function that I would like to move over to Google Spreadsheets.  This is a custom function you call in the spreadsheet, and titles and decay are two ranges (will always be used with range that has 1 row and varying # of columns) that the user defines when calling the function.

VBA code:

```
Function views(titles,decay)
    indx = titles.Count
    vtotal = 0

    For ct = 1 To indx
      vtotal = vtotal + titles(ct) * decay(indx - ct + 1)
    Next

    views = vtotal
End Function
```

My (feeble) attempt at doing this in Google Apps Script is not working:

```
function views(titles, decay) {
    var indx = titles.length;
    var vtotal = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= indx; i++) {
        var vtotal = vtotal + titles[i] * decay[indx - i + 1]
    }
    return vtotal
}
```

Can I pass ranges into custom functions as I have tried doing here?  Is there another approach that would arrive at the same answer?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: On [meta] was suggested to vote to close question that request code translation. See [Code translating tagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265825/1595451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When spreadsheet ranges are passed into a function, they are always represented as a 2D Javascript array, even if they are one row high (or one column wide). Also, I think you might have to make same minor modifications in the for loop with the "zero-based" index. If the ranges are one row high, try:

```
function views(titles, decay) {
    var indx = titles[0].length;
    var vtotal = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < indx; i++) {
        var vtotal = vtotal + titles[0][i] * decay[0][indx - i - 1]
    }
    return vtotal
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added the suggested code (but made the for loop a "one-based" index), but I receive an "error: Overflow" message when I call the function in a cell in the spreadsheet.  `function views(titles, decay) {
  var indx = titles[0].length;
  var vtotal = 0;
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= indx; i++) {
    var vtotal = vtotal + titles[0][i] * decay[0][indx-i];
  }
    return vtotal;
}`
Any ideas why or ways to ensure it returns a single value (the overall vtotal)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my answer soon after I posted, but you must have caught my original code - see the answer now - should be `decay[0][indx-i-1]`.

Comment: Yes I would try the code as in my answer - the arrays formed from the passed-in ranges will be zero-based no matter what.

Comment: Again, thank you - that worked!  For others viewing thread, final code is what is displayed in the answer (and not in the subsequent comments).  Thanks, @AdamL

Comment: There are 2 points which occur to me immediately. First there is one more iteration of the loop in your solution. Second use vtotal += instead of vtotal = vtotal +